# Is there any way by which I can save files to icloud in Cordova

Tags: cordova, icloud

I'm using cordova-sqlite-plugin, according to its documentation, the database file will be backed up by iCloud if I put it to a right directory. But it's not working. I thought perhaps iCloud dosen't support sqlite file, so I dump the data into a sql file, and put it to Libary/Cloud directory, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `config.xml`.

`<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />`